# Burp suite doesn't send accept-encoding header

Tags: burp-suite

When I send a GET request with Burp, it doesn't have "Accept-Encoding" header on it's header. Because of that, I can't get a js file from a website (It returns 406 response).

But when I add "Accept-Encoding: gzip" header manually on Repeater section, application returns 200 response.

I checked Firefox's "about:config" section, it's in default settings.

I installed "Modify Headers" plugin to Firefox, add "Accept-Encoding" header. Still, I Don't see this on my request headers.

I couldn't find any Burp plugin which adds custom header to requests.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the proxy options there is a setting "Strip Accept-Encoding headers in incoming requests". Disable this if you want gzip encoded responses.

[image: Burp proxy options]

Comment: wow! yes that's solved the issue